# One word for a person who is chasing a hopeless cause

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who is chasing a hopeless or lost cause?

Comment: A dreamer, an irresponsible headstrong person, ... you should provide more context if you want a more precise term.

Comment: dreamer is not like chasing a hopeless cause.

Comment: One definition of dreamer is : a habitually impractical or unrealistic person. (AHD) .

Comment: The word 'fantasist' is also used for someone with unrealistic expectations.

Comment: stubborn or muleheaded

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd call them **[Quixotic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quixotic)** [Oxford]

> Extremely idealistic; unrealistic and impractical:

However, Quixotic usually describes ideas (as against the three words in its definition, which can describe both ideas and people). To describe people, I think you might have to go with the character name: Quixote

EDIT: Based on the comments, I think most people, like me, are okay with Quixotic in this sense. And as @Oldbag points out, we also have 'Quixotical' (though he doesn't think Quixotic is wrong)

---

A term gaining traction is the [**incurable optimist**](http://www.forbes.com/sites/amyanderson/2013/08/05/success-follows-the-incurable-optimist/) [Forbes]

If you're flexible on the one-word restriction, you could say:

> He's **hoping against hope**.

Comment: The adjective is "quixotical', but I don't think it's wrong to describe a person as "quixotic', i.e., the meaning would be understood.

Comment: @Oldbag: I hope you're right. I think 'quixotic' should be acceptable, but you never know when some pedant is gonna throw a dictionary in your face, hence the disclaimer.

Comment: I don't find 'unachievable goal' to be synonymous with 'lost cause'. Isn't that the point of the story?

Comment: @Mazura: Even if every 'unachievable goal' isn't a lost cause, it can be argued that every lost cause is an unachievable goal.

Comment: @Oldbag, think again. *Quixotic* is indeed an adjective, as the Oxford link above shows, and [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quixotic_ADJ%2C+quixotical_ADJ&year_start=1604&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) than *Quixotical* in that role.

Comment: i don't see a problem with describing a person as quixotic. the word is named after a *person*, after all.

Comment: @BrianDonovan - "Quixotical" wasn't my suggestion -  my instinct would be to say "quixotic".  (You can blame Merriam Webster for the other.)

Answer (score 2):

> a person who is chasing a hopeless or lost cause?

There is set phrase that actually describes exactly your person and it is:

[**defender of lost causes**](http://www.wnd.com/2013/09/defender-of-lost-causes-took-on-abraham-lincoln/)

Answer (score 0):

*Fool.*

Just thinking laterally.